# Обнуление связанных переменных

Tags: javascript

есть такой код.

```
let a = {z: 1}
let b = a;

a.z = 2;
```

И получается что b.z тоже равно 2 так как мы меняем обект по ссылке.

но если я напишу

```
a = null;
```

то переменная `а` обнулится но переменная `b` нет и в ней все еще будет хранится значение
Но почему? у них же одна ссылка.

Comment: [тыц](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management#%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) - вот здесь можно подробнее прочитать про память и переменные в JS.

Answer (score 2):

Обе переменные ссылаются на одну область. Если можно так выразиться - смотрят на одну область. Присвоение переменной значение `null` лишь означает, что теперь эта самая переменная не будет смотреть на ту самую область с объектом.

Тоже самое будет если в `а` записать любое другое значение. Переменная будет смотреть на другую область, где записано другое значение.